# How do I install the drivers for my HCF Conexant modem?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, compiling, modem

How do I install drivers for my HCF Conexant modem in Ubuntu 11.10?

Unfortunately Conexant driver is old with no update for new kernel version (upper 2.6)
so I cant install and use my HCF modem.

I tried to compile it but when I want to  configure it I have error!  How should I compile and configure this driver with a newer kernel?

Answer (score 1):

How to detect the modem and install the driver using the installer

- Download the installation program ([cnxtinstall.run](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hcf/full/archive/cnxtinstall.run))
- Open a terminal window. (If you don't know how to do this, press ALT-F2 and in the dialog box that will appear, try entering one of the following commands: xterm or konsole or gnome-terminal)
- Use the cd command to access the directory where the cnxtinstall.run file was downloaded.
- Finally, enter the sh cnxtinstall.run command to run the installer.

[source](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hcf/downloads-installer.php)

Comment: I try all of this but ....at first if I want use cnxtinstall.run I need connect to internet to download driver so I cannt second pay attention that I said the drivers didnt update for new kernel so should compile drivers with som option that make it usefull I install my modem in ubuntu 10.10 but now it has problem with kernel

Comment: Download to a USB drive then install from there